# How to delete dots from display directory file

Tags: php, mysqli

My output display dots so i want to delete the dots

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
$log_directory = ('/XAMPP/htdocs/mydoc');
$results_array = array();
if (is_dir($log_directory))
{
        if ($handle = opendir($log_directory))
        {
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
                {
                        $results_array[] = $file;
                }
                closedir($handle);
        }
}
foreach($results_array as $value)
{
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
}
?>
```

***But the output***

[I want to throw the dots..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ljhG.png)

Any solution to delete the dots ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*readdir()* always return "." & "..". So you just have to validate and skip them as shown in the example #2 of the manual

> ```
> <?php
> if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
>     while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
>         if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
>             echo "$entry\n";
>         }
>     }
>     closedir($handle);
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Resulting in

```
[...]
        if ($handle = opendir($log_directory))
        {
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
                {
                    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                        $results_array[] = $file;
                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);
        }
[...]
```

Comment: Isit posible or not if I dont set path like $log_directory = ('/XAMPP/htdocs/mydoc'); ? i want see other path too

Answer (score 1):

You can try array_diff to remove the dots.

```
$results_array = array_diff($results_array, ['.','..']);
```